# HTML Element inside a Ternary Operator in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm nesting a  inside a  HTML Element, but I'm confused about the ternary operator JSX syntax.

```
<span>
              {triggerScheduleValue.n_intervals === 1
                ? (
                   `Do you want to reset the current schedule to be every ${
                    triggerScheduleValue.n_intervals
                  } ${triggerScheduleValue.interval.slice(
                    0,
                    triggerScheduleValue.interval.length - 1,
                  )} from `<b>{currentTime}</b>
                ) : (
                  `Do you want to reset the current schedule to be every ${triggerScheduleValue.n_intervals} ${triggerScheduleValue.interval} from `<b>{currentTime}</b>
                )
            </span>
```

How can i render that  inside the condition?

I didn't want to repeat all that span stuff.

Comment: JSX is not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
                (
                   `Do you want to reset the current schedule to be every ${
                    triggerScheduleValue.n_intervals
                  } ${triggerScheduleValue.interval.slice(
                    0,
                    triggerScheduleValue.interval.length - 1,
                  )} from `<b>{currentTime}</b>
                )
```

translates into

```
"Do you want to reset the current schedule to be every 1 2 from"<b>1000</b>
```

You must wrap it inside fragment:

```
                (
                   <>`Do you want to reset the current schedule to be every ${
                    triggerScheduleValue.n_intervals
                  } ${triggerScheduleValue.interval.slice(
                    0,
                    triggerScheduleValue.interval.length - 1,
                  )} from `<b>{currentTime}</b></>
                )
```

Same applies for

```
`Do you want to reset the current schedule to be every ${triggerScheduleValue.n_intervals} ${triggerScheduleValue.interval} from `<b>{currentTime}</b>
```

to

```
<>`Do you want to reset the current schedule to be every ${triggerScheduleValue.n_intervals} ${triggerScheduleValue.interval} from `<b>{currentTime}</b></>
```